# printf in html code

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to put this PHP code into an html echo...

```
*$sql="SELECT SUM(((annual + holiday)+overtime_earned*1.5)/24) FROM leave_balance WHERE user ='$user'";

  if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
    // Fetch one and one row
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
      {
      printf ("%s \n days off",$row[0] );
      }
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
  }*
```

Where 'PHP CODE OUTPUT' is where I want the php code output.

```
echo "<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>" .
                   "<li><a href='members.php?view=$user' class='active'>PHP CODE OUTPUT</a></li>" .
```

is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your code below:

```
$sql="SELECT SUM(((annual + holiday)+overtime_earned*1.5)/24) FROM leave_balance WHERE user ='$user'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo "<ul class='nav navbar-nav'><li><a href='members.php?view={$user}' class='active'>{$row[0]} days off</a></li>";
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Another way to do it would be to store it as a variable:

```
$daysoff = $row[0];
echo "{$daysoff} days off";
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a lot better than what I was getting at. However, I'm getting this                                                                                                      Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Hi @KevinS, you're getting that notice because the MySQL either has an error or is not returning anything. Can you make sure that query works by punching it in manually? You can do this from phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, or the mysql command line. Something handy to do in a situation like this is to echo the contents of $sql so you can paste the exact output into mysql.

Comment: Got it working. It was my mistake. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Let me know if you need anything else. If you're happy, an upvote and accepted answer would be greatly appreciated!